# Conditional clause with \ifnum and \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I got the following problem. My aim is to build a barplot with tikz. Using a function to display the sum of the bars in a stacked ybar I want to add a superscript to one specific sum below the x axis.

```
        show sum below/.style={
            /pgfplots/scatter/@post marker code/.append code={%
                \node[font=\footnotesize,
                at={(normalized axis cs:%
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},%
                    0)%
                },
                anchor=north,
                ] { 
                    \ifnum\pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}=2,500
                        {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}\textsuperscript{$3$}};
                    \else
                        {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}};
                    \fi};
            },
        },
```

The sum display below the x axis is in this code basically the highest point of the respective bar.

Unfortunately I run in problems in handing over the /data point/y to the if clause.

Are there any ideas how to solve this issue to build a correct input for the condition?

Here follows a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,fit,positioning,shapes.symbols,chains, calligraphy}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.14,
    }

\begin{document}



\begin{figure}[th]
     \centering
     \begin{threeparttable}[t]
     \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        
        \edef\mylst{"1963", "1964"}

        
      \pgfplotsset{
        
        show sum below/.style={
            /pgfplots/scatter/@post marker code/.append code={%
                \node[font=\footnotesize,
                at={(normalized axis cs:%
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},%
                    0)%
                },
                anchor=north,
                ] { 
                    \ifnum\pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}=375
                        {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}\textsuperscript{$3$}};
                    \else
                        {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}};
                    \fi};
            },
        },
        
    }


\begin{axis}[
            ybar stacked, 
            xticklabels={{1963}, {1964}},
            symbolic x coords = {{1963}, {1964}},
            axis y line       = none,
            axis x line       = none,
            nodes={text width=25mm, text depth=,
            align=center, font=\tiny},
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
            scale only axis,
        ]
            

            % Data 1
            \addplot[text=black
                ] coordinates {
                ({1963}, 50) 
                ({1964}, 125)
            };
            % Data 2
            \addplot[text=black
                ] coordinates {
                ({1963}, 250) 
                ({1964}, 250)
            };
            % Total 
            % Here point meta=explicit symbolic to hide the helping values 1e-500 as 0 leads to hiding sums
            \addplot[show sum below, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
                ({1963}, 1e-500) 
                ({1964}, 1e-500) 
            };
            
            
        \end{axis}


        \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{tabular}
     
     \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
     \item[$1$] Comment numero uno
   \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Your example is not minimum, nor compilable (it misses `\documentclass...` etc.). You need to post something that I can copy and paste into my editor and compile... and that shows *only* the problematic part.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and your remarks. I revised the MWE in my first in the opening entry. At least on my machine it compiles. Anyhow the problematic part is the \ifnum line show sum below/.style={... part. The idea is, that if it is a specific sum (in this case expressed as bar height) a superscript should be added to this particular sum while the other figures (or in this example just figure) should be the sum without any further remarks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `\ifnum\pgfmathparse{...}=375`, because `\pgfmathparse` doesn't work by expansion.

You should also convert the data to a format that can be actually used. With

```
% first parse the number
\pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}
% then store in \pgfmathresult the value in fixed point notation
\pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}
% store 1 if equal and 0 otherwise in \pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult==375 ? 1 : 0}
% now look whether we have equality or not
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
```

you will succeed.

In the first call the successive values of `\pgfmathresult` will be

```
1Y3.0e2]
300.00000000
0
```

and in the second call

```
1Y3.75e2]
375.000000000
1
```

Full code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{
  arrows,
  decorations.pathmorphing,
  backgrounds,
  fit,
  positioning,
  shapes.symbols,
  chains,
  calligraphy
}

\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.14,
}

\begin{document}



\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{threeparttable}[t]
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\mylst{"1963", "1964"}
  \pgfplotsset{
    show sum below/.style={
      /pgfplots/scatter/@post marker code/.append code={
        \node[
          font=\footnotesize,
          at={(normalized axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},0)},
          anchor=north,
        ]{
          \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}
          \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}
          \pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult==375 ? 1 : 0}
          \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}\textsuperscript{$3$};
          \else
            \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}};
          \fi
        };
      },
    },
  }
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked, 
    xticklabels={{1963}, {1964}},
    symbolic x coords = {{1963}, {1964}},
    axis y line       = none,
    axis x line       = none,
    nodes={
      text width=25mm,
      text depth=,
      align=center,
      font=\tiny
    },
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
    scale only axis,
  ]
  % Data 1
  \addplot[text=black] coordinates {
    ({1963}, 50) 
    ({1964}, 125)
  };
  % Data 2
  \addplot[text=black] coordinates {
    ({1963}, 250) 
    ({1964}, 250)
  };
  % Total 
  % Here point meta=explicit symbolic to hide the helping values 1e-500 as 0 leads to hiding sums
  \addplot[show sum below, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
    ({1963}, 1e-500) 
    ({1964}, 1e-500) 
  };
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
     
\begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
  \item[$1$] Comment numero uno
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for you help! Your proposed solution works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the data value `\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}` is stored in the float format. (Besides, `\ifnum\pgfmathparse` cannot be used in this combination anyway.) In order to use `\ifnum` you want it to be a plain integer. So you need to convert it. The following does that but likely not in the simplest possible way.

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\myy{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
```

Further, it is often advantageous to make the comparisons in pgf since this also works for nonintegers.

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\itest{\myy==375}%
```

The result, `\itest`, can then safely be used in an `\ifnum` statement.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}



\begin{figure}[th]
     \centering
     \begin{threeparttable}[t]
     \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        
        \edef\mylst{"1963", "1964"}

        
      \pgfplotsset{        
        show sum below/.style={
            /pgfplots/scatter/@post marker code/.append code={%
                \node[font=\footnotesize,
                at={(normalized axis cs:%
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},%
                    0)%
                },
                anchor=north,
                ] {\begingroup
                    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
                    \pgfmathsetmacro\myy{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}%
                    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
                    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\itest{\myy==375}%
                    \ifnum\itest=0
                        {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}\textsuperscript{$3$}};
                    \else
                        {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}};
                    \fi
                   \endgroup    
                    };
            },
        },
        
    }


\begin{axis}[
            ybar stacked, 
            xticklabels={{1963}, {1964}},
            symbolic x coords = {{1963}, {1964}},
            axis y line       = none,
            axis x line       = none,
            nodes={text width=25mm, text depth=,
            align=center, font=\tiny},
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
            scale only axis,
        ]
            

            % Data 1
            \addplot[text=black
                ] coordinates {
                ({1963}, 50) 
                ({1964}, 125)
            };
            % Data 2
            \addplot[text=black
                ] coordinates {
                ({1963}, 250) 
                ({1964}, 250)
            };
            % Total 
            % Here point meta=explicit symbolic to hide the helping values 1e-500 as 0 leads to hiding sums
            \addplot[show sum below, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
                ({1963}, 1e-500) 
                ({1964}, 1e-500) 
            };
            
            
        \end{axis}


        \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{tabular}
     
     \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
     \item[$1$] Comment numero uno
   \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is an interesting community. Someone can just copy the essential points of an answer, and everyone seems to appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for your solution to the problem, which works perfectly for my case.